# Show that if $S\subset \mathbb{R}$, $S\neq \emptyset$, and $S$ is bounded, then $\inf S \leqslant \sup S$

Tags: real-analysis

I proved this for a finite and/or countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but then it quickly dawned upon me that $S$ doesn't have to be countably infinite or finite. Any hints? thanks!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I was actually showing that for $S'\subset S$ that $\inf S \leq \inf S' \leq \sup S' \leq \sup S$ I showed the other parts of the inequality, but I was a little dumbfounded by proving the middle.

Comment: @JimmyJackson Everything that is true is a tautology.

Comment: @GitGud I am talking about cardinality. I forgot to write "bounded", but at any rate I'm OK with $\inf S=-\infty$ or $\sup S=+\infty$.

Comment: @GitGud Good Point!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think I misunderstood you somehow. I thought you were saying the property holds true for any poset, (and it does just as long as $\inf (S)$ and $\sup (S)$ exist).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff at first  I just constructed a $S=\{s_1,s_2,...,s_n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>1$  and used the well ordering properties of the real numbers to show that $s_1$ was the inf and that $s_n$ is the sup, but this implies that there are countably many element in $S$ which doesn't need to be true. And I had already showed that they were equal when $S$ was a singleton set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $s\in S$.  Then $(\inf S) \le s \le (\sup S)$.

Comment: Odd parentheses, though there are four of them.

Comment: @vadim123 Haaa, why didn't I think of that! Thanks